# Questions about recreating the "Add Alarm" form in the iOS Clock app

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, ios

[image]
<sub>(source: [kominetz.com](http://kominetz.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/img_0001.png))</sub>

Hello.  I'm diving into iOS development and am building my own alarm app to become familiar with the SDK.  My questions are...

1. I've played around with UITableViews a bit, but I don't understand how I would implement the table at the top half of this form.  If I had to guess, I would say it's a single UITableView, defined with one section and four rows, is that right?
2. If so, to implement it, would I just "hardcode" the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function to create each cell manually?
3. If not, is there an adopted approach to defining the layout and functionality of these types of settings pages?
4. Row #3 has a switch in it, is this a predefined cell style or a custom cell style that I have to define myself?
5. Rows #1, 2, and 4 take the user to new views when they're touched.  Is this a predefined style and or do I just implement the standard `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` functionality to push a new view onto the stack?

Thanks so much in advance for your help!  I'm going to continue researching these questions right now.

Comment: Please help me in solving my problem.i am also creating an alarm application with same features and using local notification.i want to know that how have set the repeat interval to the notification and and how have u accessed the ipod library and set it to local notification.Please help me .Please provide me some code on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your questions:

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. n/a
4. No, you have to add a UISwitch to the cell's contentView. Tip: Look at Apple's UICatalog sample code (controls sections) to see how to implement a tableview with different controls in different rows.
5. Just use didSelectRow...

Comment: i would highly suggest looking at the UICatalog sample as mentioned in answer 4. Good tutorial for all kinds of controls and common UI pieces for the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

1. For most apps, you want to implement the Application Preferences settings plist that will be used by the device's Settings application.  It's typically a good idea to keep the settings for your app consistent with how the settings work in other apps.